# Find all possible permutations or combinations with the same order

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, excel, vba

I'm trying to write a program to print all possible permutations with 8 variables where each variable has multiple choices. 
For eg. i have

```
A = {"A1"} //has only one choice
B = {"B1", "B2", "B3", "B4"} // has 4 choices
C = {"C1", "C2"} //has 2 choices
:
:
I = {"I1", "I2", "I3", "I4"} //has 4 choices
```

My output should be of the form: A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I with all possible choices of each variable and the order should be the same.

```
A1-B1-C1-D1-E1-F1-G1-H1-I1
A1-B2-C1-D1-E1-F1-G1-H1-I1
A1-B3-C1-D1-E1-F1-G1-H1-I1
A1-B4-C1-D1-E1-F1-G1-H1-I1
A1-B1-C2-D1-E1-F1-G1-H1-I1
etc.
```

I looked at all the other questions here, but i'm not able to figure out if i can use the inbuilt java permutations class for this. I tried writing a recursive program but am stuck when trying to explode each choice into all possible outputs. Appreciate any tips on how to accomplish this in either java/c++/vba since the language is not a consideration. Thanks!

Comment: Why mess with recursion, sounds like a job for simple nested loops

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your example output

Comment: @Leeor - Nine levels of nesting. It might be easier to recurse on the nesting level.

Comment: Your problem isn't related to any of the tags except "algorithm".  Start with that: write down in words the process you want to have happen, like you were giving instructions.   Once you are comfortable with that, pick a language from one of the ones you know.

Comment: @TedHopp, it might look bad, but would be easier to understand and maintain, safer (breaking conditions could get nasty), and less stack abusive. But you did use a nice trick there, +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

You can write a series of 9 nested loops that does the job in a straightforward way. This would be a mess, though, and it can be done more simply with recursion on the nesting level. (Don't try recursing on the data at each level; that's pointless.) Here's a Java solution in pseudocode:

```
String[][] DATA = {A, B, ..., I};

void printAll(int recursionLevel, String prefix) {
    String[] level = DATA[recursionLevel];
    if (recursionLevel == DATA.length - 1) {
        // last level -- actually do the output
        for (String val : level) {
            System.out.println(prefix + "-" + val);
        }
    } else {
        // recurse
        if (prefix.length() > 0) {
            prefix += "-";
        }
        for (String val : level) {
            printAll(recursionLevel + 1, prefix + val);
        }
    }
}
```

You would generate the output by calling:

```
printAll(0, "");
```